# Grouping option value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list, optgroup

How to I grouping `option value`.
here is my HTML

```
<select id="kota"> </select>
```

and my JS

```
var $sel = $('select#kota');
availableTags.forEach(function(tag) {
  $sel.append('<optgroup label="'+tag.area+'"><option value="'+tag.stationcode +'">'+ tag.label +'</option></optgroup>');
});
```

I want to separate 'label' for Jakarta and Bandung. Any body help? or suggestion?
Here is my full code in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/u1be7gkq/7/

I want expected like this 
[image]

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean when you say "I want to separate 'label' for Jakarta and Bandung" ?

Comment: @HenryDev Hey, I'm sorry, I mean from variable, likes my link https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/u1be7gkq/6/

Comment: It's still not clear to me. What is the output that you are expecting??

Comment: @dedri wibisono so do you want 2 selects? 1 for Jakarta and the other one for bandung ??

Comment: @HenryDev I'm sorry, my question is not clear, I have update my question and insert the pict, Thats what I expected, I hope you understand what I mean, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution. Hope it helps :)!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       
var availableTags = [{
    label: "Bandung - Bandung (BD)",
    area: "Bandung",
    station: "Bandung",
    stationcode: "BD"
}, {
    label: "Bandung - Cicalengka (CCL)",
    area: "Bandung",
    station: "Cicalengka",
    stationcode: "CCL"
}, {
    label: "Bandung - Cikadongdong (CD)",
    area: "Bandung",
    station: "Cikadongdong",
    stationcode: "CD"
}, {
    label: "Jakarta - Gambir (GMR)",
    area: "Jakarta",
    station: "Gambir",
    stationcode: "GMR"
}, {
    label: "Jakarta - Jakarta Kota (JAKK)",
    area: "Jakarta",
    station: "Jakarta Kota",
    stationcode: "JAKK"
}, {
    label: "Jakarta - Jatinegara (JNG)",
    area: "Jakarta",
    station: "Jatinegara",
    stationcode: "JNG"
}];

var bandungArray = [];
var jakartaArray = [];
var output1 = [];
var output2 = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < availableTags.length; i++){
 if((availableTags[i].label).indexOf("Bandung") !== -1){
  bandungArray.push(availableTags[i]);
 }
 else{
  jakartaArray.push(availableTags[i]);
 }
}

bandungArray.forEach(function(tag) {
 output1.push('<option value="'+ tag.stationcode +'">'+ tag.label +'</option>');
});
jakartaArray.forEach(function(tag) {
 output2.push('<option value="'+ tag.stationcode +'">'+ tag.label +'</option>');
});

$('#kota').html("<optgroup label='Bandung'>"+output1.join('') + "<optgroup label='Jakarta'>"+output2.join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="kota">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you @HenryDev very useful. I have to create 'array' before. Thanks for your solution